# matrix mul max value estimate

Tags: c, matrix, numerical-analysis

Given matrix product `C = A*B`, is there `N^2` way to estimate max value in C?  Or rather what is a good way to do so?

Comment: What do you mean by "estimate"?

Comment: @Oli Get the reasonable upper bound of `max(abs(C))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

1. For each row in `A` and each column in `B`, find the vector-norm squared (i.e. sum of squares).  ***O(n^2)***
2. For each combination of row from `A` and column from `B`, multiply the corresponding vector-norm squareds.  ***O(n^2)***
3. Find the maximum of these.  ***O(n^2)***

The square-root of this will be an upper-bound for `max(abs(C))`.  Why?  Because, from the [Cauchy-Schwartz inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy-Schwartz), we know that `|<x,y>|^2 <= <x,x>.<y,y>`, where `<>` denotes the inner-product.  We have calculated the RHS of this relationship for each point in `C`; we therefore know that the corresponding element of `C` (the LHS) must be less.

**Disclaimer:** There may well be a method to give a tighter bound; this was the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: i was thinking getting max of columns and row and multiplying that.  wonder ifd that might be tighter.

Comment: @aaa: That will produce a result that will always be >= the result from my method.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously,

```
N * max(abs(A)) * max(abs(B))
```

is an upper bound (since each element of C is the sum of N products of two values from A and B).

Comment: this will overestimate too much

Comment: @aaa: there may be better bounds, but you can easily construct A and B where the bound is reached, so in this sense the bound is not an over-estimation.

Comment: I might go with your suggestion if the memory becomes a concern.  Basically trying to multiply somewhat block-sparse matrices

Comment: @aaa: If your matrices are sparse, this will  *massively* overestimate, as multiplying by `N` relies on the assumption that the matrix is relatively "homogeneous".

Comment: @Oli: you are right, and I upvoted your answer already yesterday. Nevertheless, IMHO my suggestion is a correct answer to the original question.

Comment: @Doc: I agree that this is a valid answer!

Comment: @Oli I am basically looking for midground - I need screening as well as cache performance.  So I am partitioning matrices into blocks (say 16x16) and screening blocks, rather then entire matrix.

Comment: @aaa: oh, I misunderstood you.  That probably does make quite a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

this is my take:

```
A,B,C

a(i) = max(abs(A(i,:)))
b(j) = max(abs(B(j,:)))

c(i,j) = N*max(a(i)*b(j))
```

What you think?  Gonna try Oli's answer and see what gives me best approximation/performance.

Comment: I believe this will give the same result as @Doc's method.